# How to auto click a html button in WebBrowser of Windows phone 8.0 application?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

In my windows phone 8.0 silverlight application, there is an webbrowser which  will navigate to a url(the url is given). The url is of a page which have a button. When I click this button manually it will navigate to another url. Now I want to make this click auto. I mean, when the webbrowser will be loaded, it will automatically click the button and navigate to that specified url.

N.B : I am using C# language.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about WP, but I think you can use the `LoadCompleted` event of `WebBrowser` control. Write your redirection code inside the event.

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery button click can be simulated by

```
$("#myButton").trigger("click");
```